# O(log log n) algorithm for floor(√2 n)?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

I need to find an O(log log *n*) algorithm to calculate floor(√2 *n*) for a positive number *n*.

Comment: Multiplication is an constant time operation, so is truncation.

Straightforward take is a O(1) time complexity, so why do you need worse algorithm?

Comment: @milleniumbug: Multiplication is constant time only for *n* bounded by a constant. For large *n*, multiplication is more like O(log *n* log log *n*).

Comment: @Gareth Rees: Thanks for clarification - I was thinking about standard integer types multiplication.

Comment: Is calculating root 2 to an appropriate level of accuracy part of this problem?  I assume it is?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt such an algorithm is possible, since floor(√2 *n*) has at least as many digits as *n*, so it will take time O(log *n*) just to output the answer.